# Add pre-build step to android ndk-build module for header dependency?

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

Basically, what I'd like to do in an Android.mk file is:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
$(LOCAL_MODULE): pre-build
pre-build:
    @echo HI
.PHONY: pre-build
# ...
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The ndk-build system does work for `ndk-build foo`, and the pre-build step works, but if you use this library in an application, it won't do the pre-build step.

In particular, I'm trying to generate a header file (with version/date stamps etc) that is placed in the path that is used in `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` such that modules that consume the library can enjoy the header file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've done, as a bit of a hack.

It seems you can add a post-build step, fairly easily, but not a pre-build step.

*After* you `include` the build process, you can add a dependency to `$(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)` which will effectively be a post-build process that is always executed.

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): post_build

post_build:
    $echo Hi, I'm post-build.
```

If you need to be fancy and use, for example, things on your $(LOCAL_PATH), then

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): post_build

define gen_post_build
post_build:
    $(hide) python $(1)/MyScript.py 
endef

$(eval $(call gen_post_build,$(LOCAL_PATH)))
```

Comment: Good trick. The solution above does the post-build step after the compile but before the install+strip. I needed the post-build step to run very last (after the install) to copy the final .so file somewhere. To do this I used 'all' instead of '$(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)' in the left-hand side of the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way I found to do a pre-build step when building a dynamic library for one or more architectures (ABIs). This may not work in all situations.

Create an Application.mk file (if you don't have one already) with the following:

```
all: pre_build
pre_build:
    echo "This is the pre-build"
```

Note that using 'all' as above ends up doing a pre-build in Application.mk, and a post-build in Android.mk.

Comment: Yeah, indeed putting things in Application.mk is not a generic solution when you want an individual sub-project/library to do something for itself before it builds.  If that library is used in different applications with different Application.mk files then you'd have to duplicate that code for every Application.mk.

Comment: One idea that occurs to me only now for some reason is to create a dummy (empty) static library used by a sub-module, and have that dummy static library perform some action as a post-build step, using my original idea.  This is a workaround for some (similar but different) situations that occur in Microsoft Visual Studio solutions.

Comment: I agree Peter what I wrote is not ideal but at least it's simple. I just switched to Android Studio from Eclipse and was somewhat horrified to experience the poor state of the NDK support. Looks like it's makefile hacks for a little longer :)